# Performance of storing global constants in a class

Tags: php, performance, class

I've recently started using  classes in my projects, and one of the uses is to set and store global constants in a `private` array. I'm wondering if this is common practice, bad and, most importantly, slow if I'm doing lots of calls to the fetch function in the class (lots as in, whenever I need the site name, an email address or MySQL details).

I'm not posting the code because it's really basic; just a function that `returns` the value of an item in the array with the key given.

Comment: I don't understand what you are doing. Are you looking up array values, or doing database calls? Or both?

Comment: why you store the constants in an array? i would use class variables

Comment: Are you asking whether having something as a constant is better than having it stored in a class and call an accessor method to get it's value? It depends on the data I guess. If it fits better in design to be a part of a class. Performancewise I don't think there is any difference.

Comment: Optimize your database queries, don't bother with performance of variable vs constant accesses. Rather make readability the deciding factor here.

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: Thanks for your comments everyone. I'm not doing any database calls - these are just global variables for the site, stuff like it's name, admin details, server details etc. I think the general consensus is that grabbing stuff out of a class member variable is not significantly slower than doing the same with a constant?

Comment: If the code's basic, then you can certainly post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't worry about that.
Going this way, you will come to patterns Singleton and Registry. Don't use these patterns, it's anti-patterns.

Try to build design by the [SOLID principles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID), and your objects will be coupled less and less. The Site Name will be stored in the class, which will output content to the page, and other classes will not need this constant. The Email Address will be stored only in the Mailer class (or in his configuration file), and other classes will not need this constant. And so on.

Class, which contain all constants and all configurations it's kind of a '[God object](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object)', and it's an anti-pattern (bad practice) too.

Don't worry about performance of getters and setters.

Comment: Thanks very much OZ_ - good words of wisdom there. Thanks for the links too :-)

Answer (score 0):

It should be fine unless you declare hundreds of elements in that array, which will look note very nice to get and set :)

What I notice here is that, instead of storing all the information in a private array, why don't you just declare the instance variables? For example, instead of

```
<?php
class Test() {
    private info = array('sitename' => 'Site Name'; 'database' => 'Database Name');
}
?>
```

It should be a better practice to do like this

```
<?php
class Test() {
    private sitename = 'Site Name';
    private database = 'Database Name';
}

?>
```

The reason behind this is that, when you need to get a single piece of information of your website, you don't need to get the whole array and just get a element of it, which look not very nice. Using instance variables is just more convenient to get and set.

```
<?php
$test = new Test();
echo $test->info['sitename'];
$test->info['database'] = 'testDB';
?>
```

Does it look nicer and more handy with this code below?

```
<?php
$test = new Test();
echo $test->sitename;
$test->database = 'testDB';
?>
```

Comment: `$test->database = 'testDB';` and it will throw Fatal Error because `database` it's a private field. And don't try to change access to 'public'. Getters and Setters should be used.

Comment: oh I didn't notice, kid's mistake, just focus too much on your question. How about using a class that contains only declarations and is inherited by your current class? So the instance variables can be accessed privately or protectedly from the child class. Let me do the edit above.

Comment: it's not my question. 1) inheritance it's not best way to communicate between objects. Use Composition. 2) read about `God object`: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object

Comment: The problem with using this method (back to post) with getters and setters is, because the variables are hard coded, the getters and setters would have to be as well, bar `eval()`ing the arguments, which is silly. This is why I need an array, although it's not too neat.